# Forward a specific key to via the command line using ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Is there a way to get the ssh-agent to forward a specific key not configured in `~/.ssh/config`. For example I am connecting to a host on ec2 like this:

```
ssh -At -i ssh/insecure-deployer ec2-user@$bastion-instance-dns
```

or even connect directly to the instance behind my bastion instance like this:

```
ssh -At -i ssh/insecure-deployer ec2-user@$bastion-instance-dns ssh ubuntu@target-instance-ip
```

What I'd like to do is have the agent forward the same key I'm using to connect to the bastion instance in this case, i.e. the `ssh/insecure-deployer` key, but it seems that only keys in ~/.ssh/config are being forwarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized what was wrong. I need to add my key to the agent:

```
ssh-add -L
```

did not list the key.

Add the key via:

```
ssh-add ssh/insecure-deployer
```

and:

```
ssh -At -i ssh/insecure-deployer ec2-user@$bastion-instance-dns ssh ubuntu@target-instance-ip
```

works as desired.